# Set textBlock text that is inside a datatemplate from C# (XAML)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm starting to try to create a modern app with C# and XAML. I've already worked with C# but I never touched in a XAML or WPF piece of code, so I've a beginner question..

I'm using a MSFT template Hub App (XAML) but I don't know how can I set the text value on a TextBlock through the C# code if that textblock is inside the datatemplate.

Is there somebody who can help me with this one?

I already googled for it but I can't get any site with that answer/explanation.

This is an example about what I'm trying to do:

XAML:

```
<DataTemplate >
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="Assets/MediumGray.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="420" Height="280"/>
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  
                                   x:Uid="Section1Subtitle" Text="{Binding Score}"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="desc"  Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,10,0,0" 
                                   x:Uid="DescriptionHeader" Text="{Binding Test}"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="texttest" Grid.Row="3"
                                   Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

C# code:

```
public class Class1
  {
        string name = "This is a test";

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Seems like you need to learn MVVM. XAML-based technologies are suited to work with this pattern, which encourages separation of UI and data / application logic.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

Thanks a lot for you help.

Here is the code with the changed which allow me to get the variable from C#:

```
<DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.DataContext>
                            <local:Class1/>
                        </Grid.DataContext>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="Assets/MediumGray.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="420" Height="280"/>
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  
                                   x:Uid="Section1Subtitle" Text="{Binding Score}"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="desc"  Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,10,0,0" 
                                   x:Uid="DescriptionHeader" Text="{Binding Test}"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="texttest" Grid.Row="3"
                                   Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one will also walks you through many aspects of the WP development, including using devices, live tiles, etc:
http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2011/10/31/31-days-of-mango/

It's a bit old though.

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is no way to set something inside of a DataTemplate easily in c# code. However, there are some messy ways to do it through binding, converters, and selectors.

Comment: "messy ways" - I don't see how `<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}"/>` is "messy"

Comment: Do you have any example, please?

Comment: I meant messy way to make it so he can directly set it via c# like setting a binding to something outside the template and then setting that text value.

Comment: @w9jds so you think that proper separation of UI and data is somehow "messy". Nice...

Comment: When you are using a DataTemplate you usually want to make it so it builds for anything that uses the same object for that view. So what you should be doing is binding the text to a property in an object.

Comment: No @highcore I meant like creating a separate textview in the application xaml and then bind the one in the datatemplate to the one outside of it so then in code he can directly change the .text of the one textview so it automatically changes the one in the template. That is what I meant by messy.

Comment: @w9jds and why are you even suggesting that? There are much simpler ways to get this done.

Comment: @user2964193 I would recommend creating an object that has a property in it you want to have displayed in the textview. Then bind that object directly to the item using the datatemplate, and have the textview bind to the name of the property your text will be set to. Then whenever you want to change the text just change the value of the property.

Answer (score 0):

> XAML provides a simple and powerful way to auto-update data between the
>   business model and the user interface. This mechanism is called
>   DataBinding. Everytime when the data of your business model changes,
>   it automatically reflects the updates to the user interface and vice
>   versa. This is the preferred method in WPF to bring data to the user
>   interface.
>
> Databinding can be unidirectional (source -> target or target <-
>   source), or bidirectional (source <-> target).

try out the link [Learn XAML](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataBindingOverview.html).

Answer (score 0):

In abstraction, a `DataTemplate` is a *Visual representation of a certain piece of Data*.

UI elements inside a DataTemplate should reflect the state of such piece of data.

In XAML-based technologies, [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) helps in keeping the UI in sync with the data, using really clean and beautiful declarative means, as opposed to traditional procedural programming.

So, say you have a certain piece of data, like:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName {get;set;}

    public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

Then you may have a DataTemplate which represents that data, like:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="local:Person">
   <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

The key is in the `{Binding}` declarations.

See the above linked MSDN article for more information.

Comment: Thanks HighCore for you answer. I don't have the property DataType. I don't understand why I can't do something that should be so simple... Any example using a Windows 8.1 XAML / C# template?